# iPhone - Particle Designer - Cocos2d - Poor Animation Performance

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, particles

I have an issue when using particle effects.

I have designed a series of animations in Particle Designer. When I run those animations on my iPhone/iPod/iPad, I find it looks very different. The animation on the actual device looks much more jagged.

My app runs at 30fps and there is really no loss in frame rate when the animation is running. I tried bumping it up to 60 fps but that did not resolve the issue.

Here is my Code of Implementing the Particle Effect.

```
CCParticleSystem *fireEffectAnim;
fireEffectAnim = [ CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"FireEffect.plist" ];
[self addChild:fireEffectAnim];
fireEffectAnim.autoRemoveOnFinish = YES;
```

Any help in explaining the loss of quality/performance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out any NSLog or CCLog statements you may have in your program. these can slow down your app.